# Convert custom date format to user friendly

Tags: php, date

I currently have the following code in PHP which echo's a date from a mySQL database

```
//for an example
$card_info[0]['Player_DOB'] = "24/6/1987";

<td><?=$card_info[0]['Player_DOB'];?></td>
```

How could I parse this with 1 simple line to display a user friendly date? I know I could do something like `explode($card_info[0]['Player_DOB'], "/")` blah blah blah but that's the long process.

So basically is their anyway to do this with just 1 line of code to display something like this

```
24th of June, 1987
```

Comment: use DateTime class using createFromFormat() and will need 2 lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own function to parse that kind of dates or do:

`echo DateTime::createFromFormat("d/m/Y","24/6/1987")->format('r');`

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
echo $new_date = date('dS F, Y', strtotime('1987-06-24'));
```